# Key-Value Coding @UnionOfObjects

Tags: iphone, ios, collections, key-value-coding, kvc

I can't figure out what @UnionOfObjects offers that a simple valueForKey: or valueForKeyPath: can't do.

[Apple docs:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html)

> The @unionOfObjects operator returns an array containing the distinct
>   objects in the property specified by the key path to the right of the
>   operator. Unlike “@distinctUnionOfObjects,” duplicate objects are not
>   removed. The following example returns the payee property values for
>   the transactions in transactions:
>
> ```
> NSArray *payees = [transactions valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.payee"];
> ```
>
> The resulting payees array contains the following strings: Green
>   Power, Green Power, Green Power, Car Loan, Car Loan, Car Loan, General
>   Cable, General Cable, General Cable, Mortgage, Mortgage, Mortgage,
>   Animal Hospital.

In the above example,

```
NSArray *payees = [transactions valueForKey:@"payee"];
```

would return the same array of values, but with less code.  What am I missing?

Comment: These features of KVO provide much value when you use bindings on OSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I can think of immediately is that it "returns an **array** containing ..." (emphasis mine). So it'll be convenient for:

```
NSSet *someSet = ...;

NSArray *result = [someSet valueForKey:@"@unionOfObjects.whatever"];
```

It's therefore useful anywhere in Cocoa bindings where you want an `NSSet` (or other non-array collection) to push data into an `NSArray` shaped hole.

Comment: Warning for future readers: when I tried this, I got: `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '[<__NSSetI 0x7ff069d02140> valueForKeyPath:]: this class does not implement the unionOfObjects operation.` (in a playground), so it may not be safe to use `@unionOfObjects` on an NSSet at all.